# How can you make a hole in a wall with archimesh?

Tags: modeling

I am wondering what the best way to model the entire interior of a home would be. Here is a floorplan of what I am trying to model in Blender.
[image: Areas Highlighted in yellow have a carpet texture and areas bordered or colored in red have stone/marble.]

Areas Highlighted in yellow have a carpet texture and areas bordered or colored in red have stone/marble. I tried using Archimesh, but the room tool proved to be finicky as it would not allow me to have a hole in the wall which could make the hallway and kitchen entrance How can I make a hole in the wall with archimesh?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the same way as Archimesh does with the "Auto Hole" button, with a **Boolean** modifier.

Add a cube to the scene. This will be the hole, resize it as needed. Then add a *Boolean* modifier to the wall object and use the cube as *object* value. Leave *operation* setting at *Difference*, it's the default value. Last but not least, you just need to hide the cube in viewport ("eye" icon in the outliner) and for render ("camera" icon).

The camera icon is not shown be default. In Blender 2.9x, an easy way to hide the cube is to move it a collection and close the collection. (Upcoming Blender 2.93 will show the render icon by default. In older versions you need to activate it in the filter settings of the outliner. It's a so called *Restriction Toggle*.)

Comment: Be warned that when using boolean modifiers on archimesh room objects, should you change any of the room's core properties like thickness, whether there is a ceiling or floor (or not), wall covering, width, etc, it will wipe out your boolean modifiers because it doesn't check for that.  The original tutorials on the official website tell us to just use loopcuts to make holes, not sure if that has an advantage but I personally prefer the boolean method myself, just have to make sure Im not going to change the room after I commit to starting the process of adding holes.